# How to save twilio sms in database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, twilio

/* Nodejs , MongoDB, Rest Api */
I'm using Twilio service for sending OTP SMS using mobile number. But here sms are going but not saving in
the database. I'm struggling to save otp in my MongoDB database but nothing happen.

```
try {

    const { phoneOtp } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ phoneOtp });

    if (!user) {
         return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'Incorrect OTP.' 
      })
    }

    const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
    const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

    client.verify.services(process.env.TWILIO_SERVICES_KEY)
       .verificationChecks
       .create({ to: user.phone, code: `Your otp is ${otp}` })
       .then(verification_check => console.log(verification_check.status));


    user.phoneOtp = "";

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'OTP verified 
        successfully.' });
   } catch (err) {
        return res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'OTP not verified 
        try again' });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call .save on user. e.g

```
  user.phoneOtp = "OTP";
  await user.save()
```